# Problem with LegendMarkers using PolygonMarker

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to use PolygonMarkers as markers for a ListPlot and its legend. However, for some reason, the legend markers get cut off and are not shown fully. Here is an example:

```
(* creating the marker *) 
tps = Show[
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][
   "ThreePointedStar", {Offset[10], 3}, {EdgeForm[Black], 
    FaceForm[White]}],
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][
   "ThreePointedStar", {Offset[5], 3}, {EdgeForm[White], 
    FaceForm[Red]}]
  ]

(* a simple ListPlot example *) 

ListPlot[
  Table[{i, 2 i}, {i, 1, 5}],
 Joined -> False, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"},
 PlotLabel -> "F",
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"T"}], {Top, Right}],
 PlotMarkers -> Style[tps, Magnification -> 2],
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 ImagePadding -> All,
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

In this case, the legend marker is cut off. The only solution that I found is to set
 `LegendMarkerSize` to around 40. However, this does not seem like an ideal workaround; I would expect the Legend command automatically take care of the size of the markers, so that it would work for different markers with different sizes that I want to use.

Is there a way to make this automatic adjustment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, using `PlotRangeClipping -> False` prevents the clipping of the plotmarker in the plot itself.

Then the size of a PlotMarker, and how much space has to be reserved for it in a legend, is determined by the option Offset or Scaled. Just putting in Offset[50] as an option for the PlotMarker does the trick:

```
ListPlot[Table[{i, 2 i}, {i, 1, 5}], Joined -> False, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"},
PlotLabel -> "F", PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"T"}], {Top, Right}],
PlotMarkers -> {Style[tps, Magnification -> 2], Offset[50]}, PlotRange ->
Automatic, ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRangeClipping ->
False]
```